# Placing clickable DIVs side by side in a grid. Last DIV giving problems

Tags: html, css, hover, center

Hey guys so my current objective is to make a grid of clickable DIVs that have text within them and link to another website when clicked. Currently, the problem I'm having is that the last DIV in the 2nd row (and the last DIV, overall) is raised slightly above the others in the row, and I'm not quite sure why, nor have I figured out a way to fix it. As a side note, I've also been having trouble centering the set of DIVs within the page. The  technique doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a link to the webpage in question: http://thefloodplains.com/TheFloodSharkMain.html

Here's the CSS I'm working with:

```
div {
    color: #00A5D1;
    padding-top: 14px;
    }
h12 {
    font-size:36px;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
    }
a {
    Text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
}
a:hover {
  Color: #FF8B6F;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
.Row
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /*Optional*/
    max-width: 960px;
    table-layout: fixed; /* Optional*/
    border-spacing: 10px; /* Optional */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.blockx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('DownloadMusic2.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
.blocky {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('EPKIcon2.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
.blockz {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('StreamAudio.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
.blocka {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('VideoStream.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
.blockb {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('ContactIcon.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
.blockc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #00A5D1;
  background-image: url('Handshake2.png');
  background-position: center center; /* center the image in the div */
  background-size: cover; /* cover the entire div */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
}
```

The following is the HTML I have been using for the DIVs:

```
<center><div class="container">

<div class="row">

<a href="TheFloodSharkDownloads.html" title="Downloads"><div class="blockx"><a href="TheFloodSharkDownloads.html"><h12>Downloads</h12></a></div></a>    

<a href="EPK.html" title="Eletronic Press Kit (EPK)"><div class="blocky"><a href="EPK.html"><h12>EPK</h12></a></div></a>

<a href="http://hyperurl.co/sentimentalshark" title="Stream Audio"><div class="blockz"><a href=""><h12>Stream Audio</h12></a></div></a>

</div>

<div class="row">

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrcvj6Q-V4S-xad_Y_gPTFw/videos" title="Stream Video"><div class="blocka"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrcvj6Q-V4S-xad_Y_gPTFw/videos"><h12>Stream Video</h12></a></div></a>    

<a href="Contact-Social.html" title="Contact"><div class="blockb"><a href="Contact-Social.html"><h12>Contact</h12></a></div></a>

<a href="Contribute-Support.html" title="Contribute / Support"><div class="blockc"><a href="Contribute-Support.html"><h12>Contribute / Support</h12></a></div></a>

</div>

</div></center>
```

Like I said, the last DIV box seems to rise up above the plane/axis of the others. I just need a simple fix (if there is one) to make sure it's even with the others. Hopefully this can be done with ease! Thanks and have a great day / night.

Comment: Dude You cannot use h12 as there are only h1 to h6 headings. The problem with the last div is because of the heading. Its long and consuming 2 rows.

Comment: You also have `.Row` in the CSS, but `class="row"` in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code removed unnecessary css and fixed a bit of html markup as well. I used flexbox to align those 6 divs.

```
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the working example. Try not to repeat code.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxwYGV

Comment: Awesome. Seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the response. One last question: would you happen to know how to lower the vertical position of the text within each DIV? I want the text to be more centrally vertically aligned within the DIV (so a little lower than its current position). Anyways, thanks again and have a great day/night.

Comment: @theCrabNebula Ok updated the codepen link . Just added (display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;) this to .block. Then it will perfectly centre the text inside the box.